# What happened to Juliet and Beckett?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-last-guardian

At the end of *Artemis Fowl and the Last Guardian*,

> the pulse from the second portal kills all fairies inside its radius.

However, even before that, both Artemis and Holly were convinced that it would most likely

> also kill humans (Artemis had fairy magic in him, but even before that occurred to Holly she thought he’d die).

However, Juliet and Beckett are also

> within the radius.

What happened to them after they were vacated by the berserks? The above strongly suggests that they’d die. Or maybe not? Either way, they are never again mentioned for the remainder of the book, which I find suspicious, since all other “important” people are explicitly accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holly did inform Artemis that the second lock will cause Armageddon.

> Holly hugged her knees like a lost child. “The second releases Armageddon. If Opal succeeds in opening it, every single human on the surface of the earth will be killed.”
>
> <sub>Eoin Colfer, “Artemis Fowl 08 - The Last Guardian”</sub>

Holly here told what she thought the lock would do. This story was told to her by her parents, neither of whom were around when the lock was created.

Bruin firstly explains it to Opal:

> “Choose selflessly,” said Bruin’s voice from deep within the stone. “Prudence will close the gate entirely, releasing the souls and destroying the path forever. Desperation will summon the power of Danu and wipe the humans from the face of our land. Fairies shall walk the earth again.”
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

Opal explains to Artemis how the lock works.

> “So here’s how it works,” said Opal brightly, as though explaining a math problem to her kindergarten group. “If I choose the first handprint, then I close the gate forever and all fairy souls inside the circle are released—except mine, of course, as I am protected by black magic. But if I choose the scary red hand, then the power of Danu is unleashed, but on humans only. It’s a pity we won’t see too much from here, but at least I can watch you die and imagine the magic’s effect on everyone else.”
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

And again this.

> “Holly stopped struggling. “The magic shouldn’t affect a human, Artemis. Why hasn’t it released you yet?”
>
> Artemis felt the magic scanning his person, looking for something. It found that something in his eye socket.
>
> “I have a fairy eye—one of yours, remember?” said Artemis, pointing to the brown iris. “I thought my human genes could overcome that, but this is perceptive magic. Smart power.”
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

Comment: I don’t see how this explains what happens to Juliet and Beckett — they’re not even mentioned in any of these passages. I don’t have the book with me now: does Opal end up choosing the first handprint instead of the “scary red hand”?

Comment: Artemis uses Nopal to chose the first handprint, which according to Opal "If I choose the first handprint, then I close the gate forever and all fairy souls inside the circle are released—except mine, of course, as I am protected by black magic.". This explains how Juliet and Beckett survived.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the last chapter, I see that Juliet was mentioned after all (she visited Butler repeatedly): obviously, she (and by implication Beckett) survived the blast.

However, re-reading also convinced me that this is somewhat of a blunder on the author’s part: the second gate’s description immediately after it has been deactivated makes it sound distinctly as though its destruction should kill *any* living being in close vicinity, not just fairies, and that Artemis thought he would survive simply because he could *leave* the field – which he couldn’t, due to his fairy magic.

Comment: He didn't have any fairy magic left at this point. He couldn't leave because he had one of Holly's eyes. This is known from the moment of Artemis's death when Holly's eye glows green in his socket as the wave of energy goes through him and he dies.